# WebAPI - Controller vs ApiController?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

So this is kind of a semantic question I suppose.  But in my WebAPI project, I have a view that is supposed to allow a user to find resources (it doesnt matter what the resources are).  So I created a controller called `FindResourceController` which is derived from `Controller`.  I then create my view using razor and jQuery.  And my controller has a method, called Index which returns this view.
All good so far.  
But I ALSO want a `ApiController` to handle jQuery requests from my `FindResource` view.  By convention out of the box, API urls are routed like `api/FindResource/`, so I should name my api controller `FindResourceController` and derive it from `ApiController`.  But I already have this class.  So then I could name it FindResourceApiControler, but the url maps to `api/FindResourceApi/` which seems redundant.
  This just seems kind of kludgy to me.  So either I'm missing something, or this is just the way it is... so, when doing something like this what do you do in your web api project?

Edit:  So far, this is all I have found
[Link to Article](http://www.elylucas.net/post/MVC4-Quick-Tip-1%E2%80%93Put-your-API-Controllers-in-a-different-folder-to-avoid-class-naming-collisions.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is putting the types in a different namespace an option for you? You could have a Controllers namespace and an ApiControllers namespace and have a FindResourceController in each. It might cause some conflicts though so it's not a perfect solution, but it might work for you.

Comment: Yep I think that's the only reasonable way to go.  I linked an article earlier that pretty much describes that... kind of a bummer in a way. On the other hand, I wonder if Im using it right- my controllers and views have no model- I just create the view and use jQuery.

Comment: If you don't have models, and you're not using Razor much, you might as well serve static HTML files - this will actually give you a performance boost since no MVC pipeline will be generated. The only sideback is that you have to implement RoleProvider and Membership provider and handle security to routes to HTML files by web.config.